# XRDP Gets Disconnected After Some Time Automatically in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, remote, xrdp, remote-login

While using XRDP, the connection gets disconnected automatically but the PC gets running; then I have to restart to get connected again. I can't figure out why its happening and how to resolve the problem.

Comment: If you reconnect within 5 minutes, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-7 minutes"` will show you what happened.

Comment: I can't reconnect I need to restart pc for that then can  connect

Comment: [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-kiUvg7CgAt_q_Zes3xZFANodL1rMnc/view?usp=sharing check this screenshot this is the error I get after xrdp disconnects while I try to reconnect.